# How to add custom gesture android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-gesture

So there is my question. I would like to know how to add custom pattern for a gesture in Android Studio, just like: draw a tick to continue or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible as you have to use the MotionEvent enum.  An example of how this is done is shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

You'd have to look at extending this or using movement tracking to work out things like velocity of the motion, there's documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html) but it doesn't look elementary.